# Making health and food synonyms of medicine and nutrition

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Fabian just proposed [health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) as a synonym for [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) and [food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) as a synonym for the [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition).

Those who have five or more upvotes on those tags can go vote to make them synonyms:

- [Making health a synonym of medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/medicine/synonyms)
- [Making food a synonym of nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/nutrition/synonyms)

Comment: What was the thinking behind food -> nutrition? Questions about food supply such as my China question are definitely about food, but not about nutrition. Would like to get some idea of why nutrition is seen as being synonymous with food?

Comment: There are plenty of questions e.g. Allergies, GM food and organic food and the environment where I think this is not appropriate

Comment: I concur with @xiao -- the food/nutrition divide is also problematic. Not sure why you guys are sweeping tags into these absurdly broad categories; it's not healthy. No pun intended.

Answer (score 3):

How many people on the entire site have enough reputation to vote on these?  You may be waiting a while for votes either way.  :)

Comment: For medicine, [we should have plenty](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/medicine/topusers). For nutrition, we have exactly five.

Comment: I have the rep on Medicine, not health.  That's what confused me...

Answer (score 1):

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags/medicine/synonyms

> The following tags will be remapped to medicine:
>   health, healing, medical, and evidence-based-medicine

This is problematic, because you now have 328 things tagged [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) to the point that it's far and away the #1 tag on the site. Even questions like:

[Do we need to clean our ears (remove earwax)?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5722/do-we-need-to-clean-our-ears-remove-earwax)

Which is surely a [health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) question that has little to nothing to do with [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine).

Comment: Health is far too generic. It's even far more wide-reaching than medicine, in my opinion. If we want to split medicine into smaller tags, then the solution is to find smaller categories within medicine. Either way, this probably deserves its own meta question.

Comment: fine, whatever solves the problem of 328 generically tagged "medicine" questions -- many of which have nothing at all to do with medicine.

Comment: @bor this is *egregiously* wrong so I am undoing it. It's already caused a ton of damage since the #1 tag is frequently wrong. I'm bringing [health] back for now, we need to retag hundreds of questions that erroneously got [medicine] attached that have *nothing* to do with medicine.

Comment: @Borror0 Health may be too generic, but *medicine isn't even generic*. As such, it's being incorrectly applied in a lot of cases which deal with non-medicinal health. Unless one considers "wearing earplugs" to be a subset of medicine. If all 328 were about medicine, it'd be one thing, but as it stands, there are a fair amount of non-medicinal items so either way, we've got a bad tag here.