# Reorganizing the medicine and health tags

Tags: discussion, tags

We've [had some discussions on the medicine tag](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/help-us-divide-the-medicine-tag-in-an-helpful-way) and how to split it up into smaller categories. The current problem is that the tag was applied to broadly, not only to questions directly related to medicine and diseases. The health tag that proliferated again after the health->medicine tag was removed is far too vague and applied indiscriminately. The health tag does no good and I'd like to eliminate it.

Based on my original proposal I suggest the following changes:

If we keep [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) for everything concerning illnesses and health there are some questions tagged with medicine that should be moved into a different tag:

- [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition)
  This is a difficult one as many nutrition-related questions are about the effects on health of certain foods. But splitting this has probably the biggest effect, so I'm now in favor of removing nutrition questions from the medicine tag
- [physiology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology) and [anatomy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anatomy) as subsets of [biology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology)
   For all those questions that are about the human body, but not about diseases or medicine.
- [hygiene](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygiene)
   about how to get rid of bacteria and similar questions.
- [healthcare](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare)
   Some questions are not really medical questions, but about doctors, hospitals and other aspects of healthcare.
- [environmental-health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-health)
   For questions about the health impacts due to environmental sources, either natural or man-made

Based on a suggestion from Sklivvz I also think we should rename [medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) into [medical-science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-science) to remove any ambiguity.

If anyone is opposed to these changes or has any better ideas, please speak up now.

Comment: Would questions about the economics/efficacy of breast-cancer screening count as healthcare, medicine or both?

Comment: I'd count that as healthcare (if it is really about the economics/public policy), the tags are meant to be exclusive, so only one should be used.

Comment: Most of these suggestions seem sensible. But I'm not sure you can achieve a perfect split of healthcare and medical-science. The problem being (as in the cancer screening example) that the results of *medical-science* have implications for *healthcare*.